# Need help on writing a junit test for a function which is returning Flux stream as output

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I need help in writing unit test for a function that is returning Flux stream as output.

I have tried using the StepVerifier but I guess I am using it in the wrong way.

In need to test the following function.

```
public Flux<List<String>> streamCompletedScansAfterLastSubmit(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
    Flux<Long> interval = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    Flux<List<String>> completeScans = Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() -> scanService.getCompletedScansAfterLastSubmitForUser(username)));
    return Flux.zip(interval, completeScans).map(Tuple2::getT2);
  }
```

What I have tried is

```
  public void shouldPublishTheAssessmentStatusOnceFinished() {
    when(scanService.getCompletedScansAfterLastSubmitForUser(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Arrays.asList("Scan1:Success"));
    StepVerifier.create(apiScanController.streamCompletedScansAfterLastSubmit("quays_ka"))
      .expectSubscription()
      .expectNext(Arrays.asList("Scan1:Success"))
      .verifyComplete();
  }
```

I am getting error:

java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectComplete" failed (expected: onComplete(); actual: onNext([Scan1:Success]))

Somehow the service method gets called twice (I checked that using doAnswer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stream.generate(Supplier)` generates an infinite `Stream`, so `completeScans` is infinite too.

Since `interval` is also infinite, with the mock service the zipping of the two results in a `Flux` that emits `["Scan1:Success"]` every 5 second.

On the contrary, your `StepVerifier` expects a very finite `Flux` of a single list before termination, so it fails as soon as it sees a second occurrence of the list.

Comment: Yes, currently fixed it with expecting finite number of elements from stream and asserting them.

```
StepVerifier.create(apiScanController.streamCompletedScansAfterLastSubmit("abc").take(2))
      .expectNext(Arrays.asList("Scan1:Success"))
      .expectNext(Arrays.asList("Scan2:Error"))
      .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: yes, that is a good approach. you can also cancel the source after being confident you received consistent values by finishing with a `thenCancel().verify()` rather than `verifyComplete()`